# Issues with Vim while using ZSH

Tags: vim, zsh

I just changed my shell to ZSH. However, when I tried to edit a .py file in vim I got a strange error:

> "test.py" [New File] Error detected while processing
>   /usr/local/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/python.vim: line   21: E492: Not
>   an editor command: def)') line   22: E492: Not an editor command:
>   def)') line   23: E492: Not an editor command: def)') line
>   24: E492: Not an editor command: def)') line   42: E10: \ should
>   be followed by /, ? or &

However, if I comment out

> filetype indent plugin on

in my .vimrc the message goes away, unfortunately so does my smart indentation.
Does anyone know why vim would be effected by a change in shell? Or have a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim wouldn't be affected by your change in shell. If you changed your login shell to zsh, then your `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` aren't read any more; it's possible that vim was relying on an environment variable defined in one of these files, or that you have two version of Vim on your system and your `PATH` is now different so you're running a different version of Vim.

You can make `~/.zprofile` execute `~/.profile`. Zsh's syntax isn't completely compatible with sh, so you need to put zsh in compatibility mode.

```
read_profiles () {
  emulate -LR sh
  if [ -r /etc/profile ]; then . /etc/profile; fi
  if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
}
read_profiles
```

Comment: This was in fact the issue, an old version of vim leftover from who knows when was taking precedence over a newer version of vim.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its zsh put rather your plugin. It looks like your missing something from the beginning of line 21. Try pulling down python.vim again and see if that clears your issue.